# invalid signer or provider for AlphaRouter

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js, uniswap

Issue with ethers@6.7.1 and @uniswap/smart-order-router"@3.16.17
Server Error
Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value={}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)

Issue seems to be Alpha Router

I know i can lower version of ethers to 5.7 and it will be fine but i want to use new version

Don't know what the issue is or how to fix it ?

```
import { AlphaRouter } from "@uniswap/smart-order-router";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { Token, CurrencyAmount, TradeType, Percent } from "@uniswap/sdk-core";





// GET DATA RIGHT

const V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45";

// GET PRICE

const chainId = 1;

const MAINNET_URL =
  "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/Dvo7vVYfs-DH2tiabe6l24m1S5USbzRX";

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(MAINNET_URL);

console.log("provider", provider);

const router = new AlphaRouter({
  chainId: chainId,
  provider: provider.provider,`
});
```

Comment: Just as a guess, you provided a read-only rpc, you need a signer to execute transaction e.g attach a private key, seed, or user from metamask etc